# How can I load the weights only for some layers?

Tags: keras

I want to take the weights of some layers - not all, as the architectures differ - from `model_trained` and initializes `model_untrained` with it. How can I do this with Keras?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a function `create_model()` which returns a Keras model ([example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py#L47-L57)), you can initialize its weights like this:

```
from keras.models import load_model

model_untrained = create_model()
model_trained = load_model('trained_model.h5')

extracted_weights = model_trained.layers[0].get_weights()
model_untrained.layers[0].set_weights(extracted_weights)
```

Comment: the type of extracted_weights is a list.
In my case am trying to extract the features from the custom trained model at a specific layer.
seq.add(Dense(128,name ='feature_dense'))
seq.load_weights(by_name=True,filepath='weights-improvement.hdf5') # facing issue filename is not defined here

After training the model. I use the below code to point to the required layer.
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                 outputs=model.get_layer('feature_dense').output)
Here i get an error --> ValueError: No such layer: feature_dense