# VGG16 Keras fine tuning: low accuracy

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, classification, keras

I've already asked similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386463/keras-vgg16-fine-tuning), but now I have slightly different problem, therefore asking new question.

I decided to use slightly different approach instead of proposed among answers in the referenced question to train, and then fine-tune model.

> **Update**: I've replaced old question provided here with more suitable version

Here is my sequence of actions:

1. Build VGG16 model and drop top layer (call it no-top model)
2. Generate bottleneck features using no-top model
3. Train a separate fully-connected model using bottleneck features
4. Build new VGG16 model, drop top layers, and attach pretrained top-model
5. Train concatenated model on dogs/cats data

And here is a code I use to implement aforementioned sequence of actions:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', UserWarning)
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', DeprecationWarning)

from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest
from pprint import pformat as pf
from pprint import pprint as pp
import os

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, InputLayer, Lambda
from keras.models import Sequential, Model, load_model
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import keras.backend as K

import numpy as np


RANDOM_STATE = 1
IMAGE_WIDTH = 224
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 224
BATCH_SIZE = 4
VGG_MEAN = np.array([123.68, 116.779, 103.939]).reshape((3, 1, 1))
VGG16_WEIGHTS_PATH = 'http://www.platform.ai/models/vgg16.h5'
DATA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'data', 'dogscats')
TRAIN_DIR = os.path.join(DATA_ROOT, 'train')
VALID_DIR = os.path.join(DATA_ROOT, 'valid')
SAMPLES_DIR = os.path.expanduser('~/dogscats_samples')


np.random.seed(RANDOM_STATE)
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')


def get_batches(dirname, gen=ImageDataGenerator(), shuffle=True, 
                batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, class_mode='categorical'):
    return gen.flow_from_directory(
        os.path.join(SAMPLES_DIR, dirname),
        target_size=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT),
        class_mode=class_mode,
        shuffle=shuffle,
        batch_size=batch_size)

def vgg_preprocess(x):
    x = x - VGG_MEAN
    return x[:, ::-1]

def conv_block(model, n_layers, n_filters, name='block'):
    for i in range(n_layers):
        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), name='%s_padding_%s' % (name, i)))
        model.add(Conv2D(n_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='%s_conv2d_%s' % (name, i)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='%s_maxpool' % name))

def fc_block(model, name='block'):
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu', name=name + '_dense'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

def build_vgg_16():
    model = Sequential()
    input_shape = (3, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT) 
    model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Lambda(vgg_preprocess))
    conv_block(model, n_layers=2, n_filters=64, name='block1')
    conv_block(model, n_layers=2, n_filters=128, name='block2')
    conv_block(model, n_layers=3, n_filters=256, name='block3')
    conv_block(model, n_layers=3, n_filters=512, name='block4')
    conv_block(model, n_layers=3, n_filters=512, name='block5')
    model.add(Flatten())
    fc_block(model)
    fc_block(model)
    model.add(Dense(1000, activation='softmax'))
    return model

def train_finetuned_model():
    file_path = get_file('vgg16.h5', VGG16_WEIGHTS_PATH, cache_subdir='models')
    print('Building VGG16 (no-top) model to generate bottleneck features')
    vgg16_notop = build_vgg_16()
    vgg16_notop.load_weights(file_path)
    for _ in range(6):
        vgg16_notop.pop()
    vgg16_notop.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    train_batches = get_batches('train', shuffle=False, class_mode=None)
    train_labels = np.array([0]*1000 + [1]*1000)
    bottleneck_train = vgg16_notop.predict_generator(train_batches, steps=2000 // BATCH_SIZE)

    valid_batches = get_batches('valid', shuffle=False, class_mode=None)
    valid_labels = np.array([0]*400 + [1]*400)
    bottleneck_valid = vgg16_notop.predict_generator(valid_batches, steps=800 // BATCH_SIZE)

    print('Training top model on bottleneck features')
    top_model = Sequential()
    top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=bottleneck_train.shape[1:]))
    top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    top_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    top_model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    top_model.fit(bottleneck_train, train_labels, 
                  batch_size=32, epochs=50, 
                  validation_data=(bottleneck_valid, valid_labels))

    print('Concatenate new VGG16 (without top layer) with pretrained top model')
    vgg16_fine = build_vgg_16()    
    vgg16_fine.load_weights(file_path)
    for _ in range(6):
        vgg16_fine.pop()
    vgg16_fine.add(Flatten(name='top_flatten'))    
    vgg16_fine.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', name='top_dense'))
    vgg16_fine.add(Dropout(0.5, name='top_dropout'))
    vgg16_fine.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='top_sigmoid'))
    for i, layer in enumerate(reversed(top_model.layers), 1):
        pretrained_weights = layer.get_weights()
        vgg16_fine.layers[-i].set_weights(pretrained_weights)
    for layer in vgg16_fine.layers[:26]:
        layer.trainable = False
    vgg16_fine.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9),
                       loss='binary_crossentropy',
                       metrics=['accuracy'])

    print('Train concatenated model on dogs/cats dataset sample')
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                       shear_range=0.2,
                                       zoom_range=0.2,
                                       horizontal_flip=True)
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    train_batches = get_batches('train', gen=train_datagen, class_mode='binary')
    valid_batches = get_batches('valid', gen=test_datagen, class_mode='binary')
    vgg16_fine.fit_generator(train_batches,
                             steps_per_epoch=2000 // BATCH_SIZE,
                             epochs=50,
                             validation_data=valid_batches,
                             validation_steps=800 // BATCH_SIZE)
    return vgg16_fine


final_model = train_finetuned_model()
```

But the problem is that model's accuracy drastically dropped. After 50 epochs, its accuracy is around `50%`. Therefore, probably I've done something wrong.

Maybe something wrong with parameters, i.e. learning rate, batch size, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not sure if it is a right solution, but I was able to increase accuracy at least up to 70% with this code (probably the main reason is decreased learning rate and more epochs):

```
def train_finetuned_model(lr=1e-5, verbose=True):
    file_path = get_file('vgg16.h5', VGG16_WEIGHTS_PATH, cache_subdir='models')
    if verbose:
        print('Building VGG16 (no-top) model to generate bottleneck features.')

    vgg16_notop = build_vgg_16()
    vgg16_notop.load_weights(file_path)
    for _ in range(6):
        vgg16_notop.pop()
    vgg16_notop.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=lr), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])    

    if verbose:
        print('Bottleneck features generation.')

    train_batches = get_batches('train', shuffle=False, class_mode=None, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
    train_labels = np.array([0]*1000 + [1]*1000)
    train_bottleneck = vgg16_notop.predict_generator(train_batches, steps=2000 // BATCH_SIZE)
    valid_batches = get_batches('valid', shuffle=False, class_mode=None, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
    valid_labels = np.array([0]*400 + [1]*400)
    valid_bottleneck = vgg16_notop.predict_generator(valid_batches, steps=800 // BATCH_SIZE)

    if verbose:
        print('Training top model on bottleneck features.')

    top_model = Sequential()
    top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_bottleneck.shape[1:]))
    top_model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    top_model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    top_model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    top_model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=lr), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    top_model.fit(train_bottleneck, to_categorical(train_labels),
                  batch_size=32, epochs=10,
                  validation_data=(valid_bottleneck, to_categorical(valid_labels)))

    if verbose:
        print('Concatenate new VGG16 (without top layer) with pretrained top model.')

    vgg16_fine = build_vgg_16()
    vgg16_fine.load_weights(file_path)
    for _ in range(6):
        vgg16_fine.pop()
    vgg16_fine.add(Flatten(name='top_flatten'))    
    vgg16_fine.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    vgg16_fine.add(Dropout(0.5))
    vgg16_fine.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    vgg16_fine.add(Dropout(0.5))
    vgg16_fine.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    vgg16_fine.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=lr), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    if verbose:
        print('Loading pre-trained weights into concatenated model')

    for i, layer in enumerate(reversed(top_model.layers), 1):
        pretrained_weights = layer.get_weights()
        vgg16_fine.layers[-i].set_weights(pretrained_weights)

    for layer in vgg16_fine.layers[:26]:
        layer.trainable = False

    if verbose:
        print('Layers training status:')
        for layer in vgg16_fine.layers:
            print('[%6s] %s' % ('' if layer.trainable else 'FROZEN', layer.name))        

    vgg16_fine.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=1e-6), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    if verbose:
        print('Train concatenated model on dogs/cats dataset sample.')

    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                       shear_range=0.2,
                                       zoom_range=0.2,
                                       horizontal_flip=True)
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    train_batches = get_batches('train', gen=train_datagen, class_mode='categorical', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
    valid_batches = get_batches('valid', gen=test_datagen, class_mode='categorical', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
    vgg16_fine.fit_generator(train_batches, epochs=100,
                             steps_per_epoch=2000 // BATCH_SIZE,
                             validation_data=valid_batches,
                             validation_steps=800 // BATCH_SIZE)
    return vgg16_fine
```

I guess there is a way to achieve much better results with fine-tuning (up to 98%), but I wasn't able to achieve it with provided code.

Comment: Were you able to increase your accuracy? I'm seeing discrepancy in accuracy when training using bottlenecks and when training the same model with frozen layers but no bottlenecks, so I'm assuming my bottlenecks values must be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your fully connected layers look totally different from the original VGG architecture.

```
# yours
Flatten()
Dense(256, activation='relu')
Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

# original
Flatten()
Dense(4096, activation='relu')
Dense(4096, activation='relu')
Dense(2, activation='softmax')
```

Two points.

1. The last layer should be 2-class-softmax instead of sigmoid. The
   accuracy is not computed as you expect if you use sigmoid, I guess.
2. Complexity (number of neurons and layers) seems to be too low.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'll try it and post results.